# Which Ubuntu / Linux version have include plugins (Network,Audio / Video)

Tags: plugins, codecs

I have used Linux Mint years back, That version has every plugins or Codecs (we normally called Drivers for windows) means (Network,Audio/video)etc... I lost That dvd. Most of the linux versions have no plugins we have to install via terminal, I dont know much about linux, I wish to know WHICH UBUNTU / LINUX MINT HAVE INBUILD DRIVERS (PLUGINS) IN THE ISO BOOTABLE DVD/CD.

Thanks For seeing my question and Help

Comment: You can install codecs and fonts by "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras".

Comment: if i applied it in terminal will i get all the codecs all togather? mainly i need Network codecs and audio/video codecs.

Comment: Mostly correct, but what are "Network codecs"?

Comment: Codecs i mean network driver.

Comment: Codecs and drivers are quite different entities. Most of drivers are included in linux kernel. And what you said about Mint is about codecs.

Comment: Yes, I used Linux Mint on 2010-2011, i just installed it, but it includes codecs also, i got network without doing anything in terminal also audio video

Comment: I lost that dvd, i have ubuntu 10.04 and other versions but it doesn't have codecs inbuilt

Comment: After installing codecs, you will have in Ubuntu same as you could in Mint. And in most cases you get network running without any other actions. It depends on hardware. Ubuntu 10.04 is not supported. Install some more recent version, like 14.04.

Comment: can you get me the source code to install network & audio video codecs?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is not supported.

Comment: which one is the good version of ubuntu currently have & easy for installing codecs? I am using sony vaio laptop & Acer aspire

Comment: In all supported versions it is quite easy to install codecs. I suggest asking another question about which version to install on your computer. You will need to provide hardware details.

Answer (score 2):

Restricted audio/video codecs, Microsoft fonts and Flash plugin are not included in Ubuntu installation media due to legal reasons.

These codecs can be installed by installing ubuntu-resricted-extra package from Software Center or by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Note: you will be asked to accept license for Microsoft fonts, it can be done by pressing

```
<Tab>, <Enter>.
```